# Prove that 8 is the remainder of $5^{336}$ by $23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I've searched this website and while there are a few questions similar to mine, I couldn't find what I was looking for/a specific method for what I want to do.

I want to understand how one would prove that the remainder of $5^{336}$ by $23$ is $8$, or in other words, $$5^{336}\equiv 8 \pmod{23}.$$

Can anyone help me understand how one would approach a problem like this?

Comment: Hint: Look at $5^1, 5^2, 5^3,\ldots$ modulo $23$, and look for a pattern.

Comment: @vadim123 I started out doing so, but I was looking for a more abrangent method. I know that works, but brute-forcing has it's limitations (when no computer/calculator is around) and it takes too long for numbers with longer patterns.

Comment: @HolyThunder Do you have little fermat / euler at your disposal?

Comment: @AlexR now I do. This is a question I came across while studying for an exam but unfortunately I missed about half the semester's classes due to being in the hospital and I missed a lot of important material including the aforementioned Fermat's Little theorem and Euler's.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) might be interesting for you. (And maybe also some other questions in the [frequent tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) of the tag modular arithmetic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$23$ is prime, so $\phi(23) = 22$. You can thus *always* take the exponent modulo $22$ (by [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), or in this special case [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)).
$$5^{336} \equiv 5^6 \equiv 2^3 = 8 \pmod{23}$$
The last congruence is because $5^2 = 25 \equiv 2$

**Remark on Brute-Forcing**
We actually have $\mathrm{ord}_{23}(5) = 22$ so you'd have to do many computations until you arrive there. This is highly impractical.

**Remark on modulus in exponents**
We know that
$$a^{\mathrm{ord}_n(a)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$$
by definition of the order of an element. Also we know that the order of an element is a divisor of the group order, alas $\mathrm{ord}_n(a) | \phi(n)$. This allows us to make two statements:
$$a^k \equiv a^{k\bmod \mathrm{ord}_n(a)} \pmod n$$
and as a corollary of that, $a^k \equiv a^{k\bmod \phi(n)} \pmod n$.

Comment: Can I always take the exponent modulo  $\phi(mod)$? Thanks a lot man, I knew there was a way to solve these without bruteforcing them.

Comment: @HolyThunder Yes, as you see in the article about Euler's theorem
$$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \qquad\forall a$$
Computing $\phi(n)$ is easy if you know the prime factorisation of $n$.

Comment: Calculating $5^{336}$ directly is not *quite* impractical: ten multiplications, by my count, as $((((((5^2)^25)^2)^25)^2)^2)^2)^2$, all done modulo $23$.

Comment: @Lubin Square-and-multiply _reduces_ the overhead, but that's still bad when doing by hand as opposed to $1$ modulo and $1$ multiplication (don't forget all the moduli in SQM).

Comment: Absolutely: your suggestion is the only wise route to the answer. Actually, writing down all powers of $5$ modulo $23$ is not out of the question at all, especially since $5^2=2$. Once you see that $5^{22}=1$, you’re almost home free.

Comment: @HolyThunder I've added another remark on taking modulus in exponents.

Comment: Ah, cheers. This greatly improves my understanding of modular arithmetics, particularly with exponents. I really need to brush up on these. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 23\!:\ \underbrace{\color{#c00}{5^{\large 22}}\equiv\color{#c00}1}_{\rm little\ Fermat}\Rightarrow\, 5^{\large 336}\equiv 5^{\large 6+\color{#c00}{22}(15)}\equiv \color{#0a0}{5}^{\large \color{#0a0}{2}\cdot 3}\,\color{#c00}{(5^{\large 22})}^{\large 15}\equiv \color{#0a0}2^{\large 3} \color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large 15}\equiv 8 $

where we have used the fundamental [Congruence Product and Power Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

**Remark** $ $ Generally, if $\,a^e\equiv 1\pmod m\,$ then exponents on $\,a\,$ can be considered mod $\,e,\,$ i.e. $\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod m\,\ $ if $\,\ j\equiv k\pmod e.\ $ This may be proved exactly as above, i.e.

$$ \begin{array}{}\color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv 1}\\ j = k\! +\! en\end{array}\Rightarrow\,\ a^{\large j}\equiv a^{\large  k+en}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(a^{\large  e})}^{\large  n}\equiv a^{\large  k}\color{#c00}{(1)}^{\large  n}\equiv a^k\!\!\pmod m\qquad $$